# php public property default value assigning as variable

Tags: php

As I am learning PHP OOP and I see, there are lots of confusing parts. Here I have a single variable called **public $file_link** and I trying to assign default value as a superglobal variable. But I can't do like this, it gives a parse error. I am checking the whole file, again and again, to find what's the problem and I see that I cannot assign a default value as a variable in public property. so I need a setter method for public variable. **(see my code comment  for better understand)**. should I really need a method to set the value of public property??? **(any better way of doing this)**.

```
class File_Link {
    public $file_link = 'http://localhost' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];      // CANNOT ASSIGN DEFAULT VALUE
    const FILE_LINK = 'myRoot' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];                  // CANNOT USE LIKE THIS

    public $variable_name = "value";
    public $variable_name_clone = $variable_name; //                    // I GET IT -> I CANNOT USE LIKE THIS BUT IT IS A PUBLIC VARIABLE

    /*
        For a public variable i need use a setter method?????           // FOR A SINGLE LINE I HAVE TO USE THE BELOW CODE WHAT THE >>>>>
    */

    public $host_link = 'http://localhost';                             // THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
    public setFileLink() {
        $this->file_link . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a constructor to set values, like below

```
class File_Link
{

    public $file_link;

    public $variable_name = "value";
    public $variable_name_clone;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->file_link='http://localhost' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
        $this->variable_name_clone = $this->variable_name;
    }

}
```

and constants can't be changed even inside constructor once defined, as the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script

You may refer : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may
>   include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**